# Review queue indicator seems "off"

Tags: support

So a couple of us were wondering...

[image]

Why is this showing "3", but the review queues show up empty? :-)

Comment: Actually I think this indicator seems to work in a strange way :) I often find the number doesn't match the actual items to review

Comment: Yeah, I was complaining about that indicator a week ago on Slack. It seems like it's caching something.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article [Review cache indicator/timer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276031/review-cache-indicator-timer) - the queue lengths on the [review page](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/review) are cached. So it could look like there are 10 items to review, but someone has done 2 and the cached value has just not been updated yet.

Also it looks like there are still a few bugs around this calculation and that the top number is cached for a lot longer than the numbers on the review page. See these meta questions for detail:

- [Show only available review count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278330/show-only-available-review-count)
- [Why number of suggested edits showing different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270145/why-number-of-suggested-edits-showing-different)
- [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039)